# Disable add to cart button when product is on backorder on WooCommerce category archive pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I want to ask how to disable the “add to cart” button on categories and product pages. when the product is on backorder.

I tried this:

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'check_if_backordered', 1 );

function check_if_backordered(){ 
    global $product; 
    if ($product-\>is_on_backorder()){ 
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', '\__return_false'); 
    } 
}
```

But this only works for the product page. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

you can try with this snippet:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'disable_add_to_cart', 10, 2);

function disable_add_to_cart($purchasable, $product) {
    if ($product->is_on_backorder(1))
        $purchasable = false;
    return $purchasable;
}
```

Anyway, it depends on your theme integration with WC, it could be possibile that your theme does not support this flow.